# How are DOIs managed for ongoing time-series?

Tags: data, doi

I'm familiar with DOIs been allocated to historic time series, to give academics a unique, citable identifier for datasets. Similar to how a DOI is allocated to a specific journal article.

As the [International DOI Foundation](http://www.doi.org/infokit/0607DOIFAQs.pdf) says:

> A DOI name provides a means of
>   persistently identifying a piece of intellectual property on a digital network and associating it with related
>   current data in a structured extensible way.

What's the procedure for DOIs for datasets that continue to grow: for example, a time-series of external temperature data for an airport? Is one DOI allocated to the ever-growing time-series. Is there a DOI for each year's worth of archived data? Something else?

Comment: Maybe you want to give an example of a dataset that has a DOI? I was not aware that this is even a thing.

Comment: @xLeitix See, for example, the [Data cite FAQ](https://www.datacite.org/faq).  There are also many Q&As on the topic on [Opendata.SE] Stack Exchange.

Comment: That being said, I think this question might get better answers on [OpenData.SE].

Comment: I agree with gerrit. This question is much better suited for the Open Data site than here.

Comment: *If* it is off topic here, I think we should let it get closed first before considering migration; see [this meta discussion](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1606/when-did-doi-questions-become-off-topic-here/)

Comment: @xLeitix All data sets at the [Dryad Data Repository](http://datadryad.org/) receive a DOI, and this is the case for most other data repositories as well.

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem to be an *absolute* rule, though "new DOI for a new version" seems most common. Speak to whoever's hosting your data in case they have a different preference.

The California Digital Library [summarises various approaches here](http://datapub.cdlib.org/datacitation/). Some require registering a new DOI for each new tranche of the data; some will reuse the DOI but use a new version number or date to help you identify the relevant bit; some distinguish between major and minor additions.

It's worth noting that the "generate a new DOI for a new version" approach assumes that you're adding, say, a new month's data to the set with each version. If it's being updated on a daily or hourly basis, this approach breaks down; you don't want to generate dozens of DOIs for only marginally different versions! Here, the "snapshot" approach [recommended by the Digital Curation Centre](http://www.dcc.ac.uk/resources/how-guides/cite-datasets) is much more efficient - produce a static copy of the dataset as it currently stands, on an as-needed basis or at standard intervals, and cite that.

---

**Update**: the new [STM Report on scholarly publishing](http://www.stm-assoc.org/2015_02_20_STM_Report_2015.pdf), out today, notes that the "The RDA Data Citation Working Group is investigating possible
technical solutions [for dynamic data]" without giving much more detail (p. 140); the most recent material to come out of that group seems to be [this workshop report](https://rd-alliance.org/system/files/documents/Worksho%20Report%20London%20July%201-2%202014.pdf) from last year.

Comment: That's a great collection of links. All of these approaches and variations on them are used in the wild. Worth noting that the [DataCite metadata schema](http://schema.datacite.org/) (for dataset DOIs) allows for various types of link between datasets, including "is new version of" and "is previous version of".